# Sorting iText bookmarks

Tags: itext

Is there a way in iText to sort the bookmarks?

With it still keeping the correct location?

Im producing an error report and would like to sort the type of errors in the report.

Thank You

Comment: What do you mean when you use the word "bookmarks"? Are you talking about outlines? Are you talking about named destinations? How and where would one see that outlines or named destinations are sorted? Currently, your question is unclear.

Comment: In addition to Bruno's remarks, can you please tell us how you want sort? Alphabetically? Page-based? etc...

Comment: Im sorry. I was talking about the outlines. I thought they were the same as bookmarks. \n I would like to to sort it alphabetically. \n \n I bought iText 2nd edition and I found it has the list and list items after I made the post. So Im going to try that using new Paragraph with the page event. \n I hope Im making sense.

Comment: This is my sort bookmarks: Warning, Im a total newbie.